# HashMap - getting First Key value

Tags: java, hashmap

Below are the values contain in the HashMap

```
statusName {Active=33, Renewals Completed=3, Application=15}
```

Java code to getting the first Key (i.e Active)

```
Object myKey = statusName.keySet().toArray()[0];
```

How can we collect the first Key "Value" (i.e 33), I want to store both the "Key" and "Value" in separate variable.

Comment: You do realise that `HashMap` entries are unordered, and so "first" could change whenever you modify the map?

Comment: Do you understand that there's no specific order in a `HashMap`? If you modify it at all, you may get the results in a completely different order.

Comment: No, order is not guaranteed from run to run, but within the same thread, order can be relied on.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually this is a really valid question.  In Groovy there are a lot of cases where you get back a structure that looks like a list of maps, each map with a single entry.  So far I have not found an easy/obvious(Groovy) way to print out all the values.  If the keys are constant, it's as easy as collection.each{println it.key} to print out each value, but without constant keys it's not obvious, but collection.each{println it.values()[0]} works (A refinement of some of the answers here...).

Comment: @BillK: If you know each map has exactly one entry, then that's a different question really, and one that makes more sense.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
 Map.Entry<String,String> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
 String key = entry.getKey();
 String value = entry.getValue();
```

Keep in mind, `HashMap` does not guarantee the insertion order. Use a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the order intact.

Eg:

```
 Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 map.put("Active","33");
 map.put("Renewals Completed","3");
 map.put("Application","15");
 Map.Entry<String,String> entry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
 String key= entry.getKey();
 String value=entry.getValue();
 System.out.println(key);
 System.out.println(value);
```

Output:

```
 Active
 33
```

**Update**:
Getting first key in `Java 8` or higher versions.

```
Optional<String> firstKey = map.keySet().stream().findFirst();
if (firstKey.isPresent()) {
    String key = firstKey.get();
}
```

Comment: I know this is an very old answer.. this is working for hashmaps with key and value as strings. but when trying the same with object for a value getting casting error: `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to...` ... my class which I stated instead of the `String` in the right place... can't  find answer online..help

Comment: @darthydarth you should use proper type based on your context.

Comment: first super thanks for answering! was not expecting it... second I do, found that there is an issue with Generics not saved in runtime. eventually I hacked around it by using `Gson` to convert value object to a `String` and then parse it back to my class type. Its ugly but I really could not find any other solution to something that is so easy to do in other languages (I learing Java now)

Comment: sure but how? its too much for the comments section

Comment: @darthydarth you can send me an email. ruchiragayan@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159539/discussion-between-ruchira-gayan-ranaweera-and-darthydarth).

Comment: @SimonBaars No, HashMap does not thread safe by design. But you can make it thread safe based on your use of the HashMap. You can directly use HashTable but you should keep in mind it also has performance concern over HashMap.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera What would be the code when trying to retrieve the first element threadsave using a java.util.Hashtable? And wouldn't the following be threadsafe: `map.keySet().toArray()[0]`?

Comment: Quick Question: is `map.entrySet().iterator().next()` a o(1) runtime or o(n) runtime. Thanks if anyone can answer...

Answer (score 102):

To get the "first" value:

```
map.values().toArray()[0]
```

To get the value of the "first" key:

```
map.get(map.keySet().toArray()[0])
```

Note: Above code tested and works.

I say "first" because HashMap entries are not ordered.

However, a LinkedHashMap iterates its entries in the same order as they were inserted - you could use that for your map implementation if insertion order is important.

Comment: you first need to check that the map is not empty

Answer (score 63):

Java 8 way of doing,

`String firstKey = map.keySet().stream().findFirst().get();`

Comment: if we have the key, retrieve the first value using map.get(firstKey). Just a hint. :)

Comment: Do NOT use this approach! If the `map` variable is from type HashMap, this will NOT work reliably, convert to an Array or LinkedHashMap instead!

Comment: Depending on how Exception-safe you want to be, `if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {` can be pre-pended.

Answer (score 12):

You may also try the following in order to get the entire first entry,

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry = map.entrySet().stream().findFirst().get();
String key = entry.getKey();
String value = entry.getValue();
```

The following shows how you may get the key of the first entry,

```
String key = map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).findFirst().get();
// or better
String key = map.keySet().stream().findFirst().get();
```

The following shows how you may get the value of the first entry,

```
String value = map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().get();
// or better
String value = map.values().stream().findFirst().get();
```

Moreover, in case wish to get the second (same for third etc) item of a map and you have validated that this map contains at least 2 entries, you may use the following.

```
Map.Entry<String, String> entry = map.entrySet().stream().skip(1).findFirst().get();
String key = map.keySet().stream().skip(1).findFirst().get();
String value = map.values().stream().skip(1).findFirst().get();
```

Comment: I've noticed that if you know the map only contains 1 value, the iterator `keys.values().iterator().next();` is much faster than the `keys.values().stream().findFirst().get();` If you know the function is going to be called often, and most of the time the map will hold only one value, this might be a performance optimization.

Answer (score 8):

**Kotlin Answer**

Get first key then get value of key. Kotlin has "***first()***" function:

```
val list = HashMap<String, String>() // Dummy HashMap.

val keyFirstElement = list.keys.first() // Get key.

val valueOfElement = list.getValue(keyFirstElement) // Get Value.
```

Comment: I don't know but with me it returns the last value not the first one I don't know why

Comment: Do you change or update your list? Maybe you get key with "list.keys.first()" then you try to get value but your list already changed.

Answer (score 4):

> how can we collect the first Key "Value" (i.e 33)

By using `youMap.get(keyYouHave)`, you can get the value of it.

> want to store the Both "Key" and "Value" in separate variable

Yes, you can assign that to a variable.

Wait .........it's not over.

If you(business logic) are depending on the order of insertions and retrieving, you are going to see weird results. Map is not ordered they won't store in an order. Please be aware of that fact. Use some alternative to preserve your order. Probably a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Answer (score 4):

Note that you should note that your logic flow must never rely on accessing the `HashMap` elements in some order, simply put because `HashMap`s are not ordered `Collection`s and that is not what they are aimed to do. (You can read more about odered and sorter collections in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084146/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ordered-and-a-sorted-collection)).

Back to the post, you already did half the job by loading the first element key:

```
Object myKey = statusName.keySet().toArray()[0];
```

Just call `map.get(key)` to get the respective value:

```
Object myValue = statusName.get(myKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the insertion order isn't respected in a map generally speaking. Try this :

```
    /**
     * Get the first element of a map. A map doesn't guarantee the insertion order
     * @param map
     * @param <E>
     * @param <K>
     * @return
     */
    public static <E,K> K getFirstKeyValue(Map<E,K> map){
        K value = null;
        if(map != null && map.size() > 0){
            Map.Entry<E,K> entry =  map.entrySet().iterator().next();
            if(entry != null)
                value = entry.getValue();
        }
        return  value;
    }
```

I use this only when I am sure that that `map.size() == 1` .

Answer (score 1):

Improving whoami's answer. Since `findFirst()` returns an `Optional`, it is 
a good practice to check if there is a value.

```
 var optional = pair.keySet().stream().findFirst();

 if (!optional.isPresent()) {
    return;
 }

 var key = optional.get();
```

Also, some commented that finding first key of a `HashSet` is unreliable. But sometimes we have `HashMap` pairs; i.e. in each map we have one key and one value. In such cases finding the first key of such a pair quickly is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Also a nice way of doing this :)

```
Map<Integer,JsonObject> requestOutput = getRequestOutput(client,post);
int statusCode = requestOutput.keySet().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Empty"));
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also try below:

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = myMap.firstEntry();
System.out.println("First Value = " + entry);
```

Comment: There's no such method