# One class implemeting two interfaces java

Tags: java, interface

i have one class implemeting two different interfaces  ,example:

```
public interface SortList{
void Sort();
search();
delete();
}

public interface unSortedList{
search();
delete();
}

class List implements ordenedList,unordenedList{}
```

I wanted to switch between ordened interface or not ordened list,thank you for your help.

Comment: This is very unclear.  Please illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: You have to stick to Java syntax: can you complete the signature of the different methods like `search()` and `delete()` ? also, what does `ordenate()` is supposed to do ?

Comment: ordenate sorts the array,it's the only difference between then,i just have temperatures of days inside,i must be able to manipulate them if they are sorted or not,that's why i wanted to use two interfaces instead of one for the same class

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 different class like OrderedList and UnorderedList. Implements are just a guarantee you have implemented those mehtots. So you have to make a switch case or if else in your methods or you have to make two different class.

Comment: so why it's usefull for a class that implements two interfaces if i must do a switch instead of decide which interface i want to implement :S

Comment: Because *most of the time* the two interfaces don't have methods in common OR they have the same meaning ... by design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what meaning you put behind `"Ordened"` and `"UnOrdened"`, and if it makes sens to have a class implementing both, but anyway, here is an example on how you can use multiple implementations of interfaces, trying to keep up with your stuff. 
I suppose by *ordered* the Java meaning as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084146/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ordered-and-a-sorted-collection), which is **not** *sorted*.

Let's say an `Ordered` interface gives the possibility to access some object (of type `T`) by index and to search or find for a given object:

```
public interface Ordered<T> {
    T getNth(int i);
    T find(T o);
}
```

Let's say an `UnOrdered` interface provides only the way to find an object:

```
public interface UnOrdered<T> {
    T find(T o);
}
```

Now we can defined a class that implements both interfaces:

```
public class MyList<T> implements Ordered<T>, UnOrdered<T> {
    List<T> theList;

    public MyList(T...a) {
        theList = Arrays.asList(a);
    }

    // The list of objects are neither sorted nor hashed. 
    // Only way to find an object is to iterate through the list
    public T find(T o) {
        for (T e : theList) {
            if (e.equals(o)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T getNth(int i) {
        return theList.get(i);
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyList<Integer> mylist = new MyList<>(2,8,6,1,7,3,5,9,10,4);
    System.out.println(mylist.getNth(3));
    // => print 1
    System.out.println(mylist.find(3));
    // => print 3
    System.out.println(mylist.find(42));
    // => print null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have done a better job in describing the problem and what you are trying to solve for, assuming that I understood the problem, you can achieve this with `Java 8 Default methods` here is how

```
  public interface UrdenedList{
        void ordenate();
        default T search(){
          // default implementation here
        }
        default void delete(){
         // default implementation here
        }

    }

    public interface UnordenedList{
        default T search(){
          // default implementation here
        }
        default void delete(){
         // default implementation here
        }

    }
```

> I wanted to switch between ordened interface or not ordened list,thank
>   you for your help.

```
class List implements OrdenedList,UnordenedList{
   void ordenate(){
  // implementation here
}

T search(){
 if(condition)
    return OrdenedList.search();
  else 
    return UnordenedList.search();
}
}

void delete(){
  if(condition)
    OrdenedList.delete();
  else 
    UnordenedList.delete();
}
}
```

Notice Resolving conflicts by Explicitly choosing to call methods from interfaces OrdenedList, and OrdenedList