# Doesn't std::unordred_map preserve insertion order?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

My understanding of what `unordered_map` means is that is stores unit value per key without ordering them. But is it expected that insertion order is not preserved?

When I compile and run:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,int> temp;
temp["Start"] = 0;
temp["Read"] = 0;
for ( auto iter : temp )
{
    std::cout << iter.first.c_str();
}
```

With VS2015, it outputs

```
Start
Read
```

With GCC 4.9 for Android, it outputs:

```
Read
Start
```

Is it a bug, or expected?

Comment: What part of "unordered" is unclear?

Comment: Hashing........

Comment: @CoryKramer: I was expecting "unordered" not to change the order. But I was wrong....

Comment: you might be confusing "ordered" with "sorted" - ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084146/what-is-the-difference-between-an-ordered-and-a-sorted-collection eg.

Comment: If you need to preserve order, consider using `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::queue` or `std::deque`.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: Definitely. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. In the standard there're no guarantees regarding the order  of elements in `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/):

> Internally, the elements in the unordered_map are not sorted in any particular order with respect to either their key or mapped values, but organized into buckets depending on their hash values to allow for fast access to individual elements directly by their key values (with a constant average time complexity on average).

I think that pretty much sums it up.