# Is NSDictionary key order guaranteed the same as initialized if it never changes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I've run into the same problem as found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090/nsdictionary-with-ordered-keys). However, I have a follow-up question. I seem to be in the same situation as the original asker: I have a plist with a hierarchy of dictionaries that define a configuration screen. These are *not* mutable and *will* stay the same throughout the application. Since the original discussion seems to focus on problems arising from mutating the dictionary, I must ask for comfirmation: is the order of a dictionary guaranteed the same as they are in the plist, i.e. as it is read (with initWithContentsOfFile)? Can I use allKeys on it in this case to get a correct-order array of keys if the dictionary never changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the keys are not likely to appear in the same order as your `plist` file. I can't look under the hood, but I would guess that the keys are ordered in whatever way that provides an efficient look-up. The documentation for [`allKeys`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHBEJJB) says that the order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Comment: My app does show them in the same order as the plist, which was one of the reasons I started wondering. But I now know that it's undefined nonetheles.

Comment: In my app they don't always show up in the same order as plist - depends on the plist being read at the time.

Answer (score 7):

If you need an `NSDictionary` that maintains order, take a look at [CHDataStructure's `CHOrderedDictionary`](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/chdatastructures), which does exactly that.  I use it all the time.

Comment: I need it on the iPhone, so Cocoa Touch. I wonder if it runs on that? In any case, I'll answer my own question: no, NSDictionary can apparently never be expected to be in any order. So, I'm doing what I've seen others suggest: include an array with the order and key "_order". People have been saying this clunky double data-keeping isn't that clunky at all in their opinion. Still clunky, though.

Comment: Yes, the CHDataStructures runs on both Mac and iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

**I would not assume that the keys will be in any kind of order because `allKeys` does not guarantee order.**

Internally, [`NSDictionary` uses a hash table](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-9552).

From [`allKeys` description](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys):

> The order of the elements in the array
>   is not defined.

If you want to display values in some order then get the keys, sort the keys array and then get the value for each key.

Answer (score 3):

*Nothing at all* is guaranteed about order. It’s not even guaranteed that iterating over a dictionary twice will give you the keys in the same order.