# Incomplete and randomly loading NSDictionary all keys into NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

When Loading all key's value of `NSDictionary` into NSArray class.
its incompletely and jumbling (randomly) loading key value of dictionary into NSArray class

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
            //do sth
        colorNameList = [[ColorModelClass colorListNames]allKeys];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]

Issue is:
i expect all key load from dictionary into array in sequentially not randomly with out missing any key's

Comment: NSDictionary keys aren't ordered. Even in the moment that you create your dictionary, your keys aren't being stored in the order that you added them. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123188/4370893

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2496484/4370893

Comment: refer http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Answer (score 1):

I think if you need to sort your dictionary and then store it in your array, it may worked,

Try to sort your Dictionary by doing bellow code:

```
keyArray = [dicWebColors allKeys];
keyArray = [keyArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

Then proceed to store your data into the array.

Thanks

Comment: First get the keys, then sort the array. You can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: "sort your dictionary and then store it in your array" is the other way around.

Comment: @Willeke you can't sort your dictionary without array, and if you read the question carefully then perhaps you understand y did i say that.

Comment: `keyArray = [dicWebColors allKeys];` puts the keys in an array. `sortedArrayUsingSelector` sorts the array. You can't "sort your dictionary". Read your answer carefully.

Comment: @Willeke Do you have any better answer ?? Just post it down, let us help with your understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of "sort your dictionary and then store it in your array" say "store the keys in an array and then sort the array".