# Why is my NSDictionary keys sorted alphabetically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im using an NSDictionary from a tutorial that i found, but I just had a quick question as to why it is being sorted alphabetically?

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:userName, nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Other Data", @"Second Entry", nil];

    NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:array, @"Name", array2, @"A",nil];

    self.sortedKeys =[[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you are sorting them alphabetically?

```
self.sortedKeys =[[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

---

Note that a dictionary's keys are *inherently unordered*.   If you need some kind of sort order applied to the keys, you'll need to maintain it yourself separately from the dictionary.

Comment: If I just wanted them to be sorted as entered how might i do that?

Comment: There’s no way to make the standard `NSDictionary` keep the keyes ordered, see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090).