# json value not coming in serial order

Tags: iphone, json

In JSON
data order in response string and data order when parsed in NSMutableDictionary through [JSONvalue] is differ ?
I want order in response string and response dictionary should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not sorted based on keys and it may be cumbersome to do so.
I usually solve it following way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[[statesDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] retain];
```

use `sortedKeys` to access the dataDict to get proper data.

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements in an NSDictionary is undefined per definition, so there is no way you can iterate over elements and expect them to be in some specific order.

The easies approach is to keep the keys in a separate NSArray. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090/nsdictionary-with-ordered-keys) answer for more robust solutions.