# Override hash value of NSArray

Tags: objective-c

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984624/337735) shows that the hash of an NSDictionary is the number of entries in the dictionary. ([Similarly, the hash of an NSArray is its length](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFArray.c).) The answer goes on to suggest creating a category to provide a better hash implementation.

> If you need to have a more accurate hash value, you can provide one
>   yourself in an Obj-C category.

But when I try this, it appears to use the original hash implementation anyway.

We have the header in `NSDictionary+Hash.h`

```m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (Hash)
- (NSUInteger)hash;
@end
```

And the implementation in `NSDictionary+Hash.m`:

```m
#import "NSDictionary+Hash.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Hash)

- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    // Based upon standard hash algorithm ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/4393493/337735
    NSUInteger result = 1;
    NSUInteger prime = 31;
    // Fast enumeration has an unstable ordering, so explicitly sort the keys
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529761/337735
    for (id key in [[self allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
        id value = [self objectForKey:key];
        // okay, so copying Java's hashCode a bit:
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode()
        result = prime * result + ([key hash] ^ [value hash]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

A simple unit test shows the original implementation is in use:

```m
#import "NSDictionary+Hash.h"

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface NSDictionary_HashTest : SenTestCase
@end

@implementation NSDictionary_HashTest

- (void)testHash
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"val1", @"key1", @"val2", @"key2", nil];
    NSUInteger result = 1;
    result = 31 * result + ([@"key1" hash] ^ [@"val1" hash]);
    result = 31 * result + ([@"key2" hash] ^ [@"val2" hash]);
    STAssertEquals([dict hash], result, nil);
}

@end
```

This test fails with "'2' should be equal to '2949297985'".

Now, if I rename the method from hash to hashy (for example) in the category header and implementation files, then `[dict hashy]` returns the correct value. Is it not possible to override a "built-in" method in a category? Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Cody, you definitely can override built in methods with categories.

Comment: It used to be the case, and I am uncertain of the current situation, that if you had two categories with the same method name implemented, and both categories were part of a single class, the link order determined which method would actually be invoked by the runtime. A lot has changed in Objective-C over the last five years, so this behavior may be different now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSDictionary is a class cluster — when you send messages to an NSDictionary, what you interact with is never an actual instance of NSDictionary, but an instance of a private subclass. So when you override the `hash` method in your category, it is indeed overriding that method in NSDictionary, but the concrete subclass has its own `hash` method, so it overrides yours.

If you really want to do this, I think you'll want to check for the existence of the classes NSDictionaryI and NSDictionaryM and dynamically override their `hash` methods. But this is messing around in internal implementation details, and I would not recommend doing this unless you're somehow in really dire straits. If you profile and find NSDictionary's `hash` method is a problem, I would try creating a class that wraps an NSDictionary but provides its own custom `hash` method before mucking around with the private implementation classes — the implementation classes can change (and have before) without warning, so any design that relies on them is brittle.