# How to set a value in an unordered_map and find out if a new key was added

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, hashmap, unordered-map

How can I efficiently and idiomatically set a value in an `unordered_map` *and* find out if a new key was added:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main() {
  auto map = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>{{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}};

  map["foo"] = 3;
  // how to find out if a new key was added?
}
```

I can't use `insert()` directly because I want to overwrite the value if there is one already and `insert` does not do that. I can't use `operator[]` directly because it provides no information about whether a new key was added.

I want to avoid doing two searches in the map for performance reasons.

One trick I've seen elsewhere is to get a reference and check if that value is default constructed:

```
auto& value = map["foo"];
if(value == 0) {
    // am inserting a new key
}
value = 3;
```

But I can genuinely have default constructed values in my map so a default constructed value is not a good indication of new key.

The best I can come up with so far is:

```
auto size_before = map.size();
map["foo"] = 3;
if (map.size() > size_before) {
    // am inserting a new key
}
```

which seems ugly and it assumes that getting the size of an `unordered_map` is cheap (is it?).

It looks like [`unordered_map::insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign) might be the answer to my prayers but sadly it comes in C++17 so I probably wont be able to use it for another 5 years or so. It seems like quite a common thing to want to do so I assume there must be a reasonable way of doing it currently.

Comment: `size()` is guaranteed to be O(1).

Comment: "it assumes that getting the size of an `unordered_map is cheap` (is it?)." [fortunately, it should](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/size) (see complexity). As you said, without `insert_or_assign`, there is no way to do that in a single line yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `std::unordered_map::insert` and testing result.

With helper function:

```
template<typename Map, typename T>
std::pair<typename Map::iterator, bool>
insert_or_assign(Map& m, const typename Map::key_type& k, const T& t)
{
    auto p = m.insert({k, t});
    if (!p.second) {
        // overwrite previous value
        p.first->second = t;
    }
    return p;
}
```

and then

```
auto p = insert_or_assign(map, "foo", 3);
if (p.second) {
    // inserted
} else {
    // assigned
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Ym8Dyx)

Comment: As I said, I can't use `insert` because I want to overwrite the value if there is one already and `insert` does not do that.

Comment: @user3467895: That's why I assign it if insertion *failed*

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: @user3467895: edited to add helper function, so usage is easier.

Comment: But did you mean `p.first->second = 3;`?

Comment: @user3467895: Yes, sorry for the typo. Demo added so now all typos are fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) member function which will return a `pair` which returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.  It would look like

```
if (map_name.insert(some_value).second)
    value was inserted
else
    value was not inserted
```

If you need to modify the value in the map when the element is not inserted then you can use

```
auto ret = map_name.insert(some_value);
if (!ret.second)
    *(ret.first) = some_value;
```

**EDIT: UPDATE**

Starting in C++17 `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`  have the member function `insert_or_assign()`.  This function will insert into the container if the key/value pair is not in the map and will overwrite the existing value in the container if the key already exist.  The function will return a `std::pair` that contains an iterator to the inserted/updated element and a bool signaling if there was an insertion or not.  If there was an insertion then it will be `true` otherwise `false`

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> foo = { { "foo", 1 },{ "bar", 2 } };
auto ret = foo.insert_or_assign("foo", 3);
if (ret.second)
    std::cout << "foo was inserted";
else
    std::cout << "foo already exist.  new value: " << ret.first->second;
```

Output:

```
foo already exist.  new value: 3
```

I cannot find an online compiler that supports C++17 at the moment that I can share the code on but you can run it [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) or in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Comment: As I said, I can't use `insert` because I want to overwrite the value if there is one already and `insert` does not do that.

Comment: @user3467895 As [Jarod42](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) shows in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31792377/4342498) you can.

Comment: @user3467895 how about you RTFM before complaining under every single (correct) answer?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant but this answer is _not_ correct (as it stands). I misread Jarod42's answer, I apologize.

Comment: @user3467895 I am now showing how you can call insert and change the value if it is not inserted.